# How to use column wise verticle grid using Bootstrap in HTML

Tags: html, grid, bootstrap-4

I  been trying to display below attached image **vertical column wise Grid view** using **Bootstrap in HTML**. Can give me some idea for how we can achieve this .

Now i am normally display row wise column grid with reference of Grid systems on w3school.but this are not responsive to mobile view. So I need to display on vertical [image: Display Grid Like that]

*Thank you in advance !!*

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I divided thesection into vertical columns. Inside each column I inserted row class to further divide row into column.

```css
h2,h1 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="text-center clearfix">
  
  <!-- Divided sections into column-->
  <div class="col-4 float-left" style="background-color:red">
    <h1>col-1</h1>
    
    <!-- Each column contains row-->
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #ff3333">
    
      <!-- You can further divide vertical column-->
      <div class="col-6"> 
        <h2>item-1(a)</h2> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-6"> 
        <h2>item-1(b)</h2> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #ff4d4d">
      <h2>item-2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-4 float-left" style="background-color:green">
    <h1>col-2</h1>
    <div class="row" style="background-color:#1aff66">
      <h2>item-1</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="col-4 float-left" style="background-color:blue">
    <h1>col-3</h1>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #0069cc">
      <h2>item-1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #4d94ff">
      <h2>item-2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #b3d1ff">
      <h2>item-3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #cce6ff">
      <h2>item-4</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Work for me. Helpful solution

Answer (score 0):

For vertical column wise Grid view you can use

```js
$('.grid').masonry({
  // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  // use element for option
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
})
```

```css
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { width: 20%; }
/* 2 columns */
.grid-item--width2 { width: 40%; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <!-- width of .grid-sizer used for columnWidth -->
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall.

You can use this link for reference 
https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank You! but this solution display horizontal grid, I need  verticle

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap 4 flex utility

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/